Why is the energy lost by an electron in passing though the LED = energy of the emitted photon?
I understand that the energy of the emitted photon = energy between the conduction band and valence band, but why does the work done by pushing the electron through the depletion region equal the energy the electron loses to jump from the conduction band to the valence band?
Also, during diffusion before the junction reaches equilibrium, do the electrons emit photons too when come in contact with holes? If so, is the wavelength of the photon the same as those that are emitted when a voltage is applied?

Electrons and holes recombine, releasing the photon as they become no more.

The work done to push an electron through the depletion region depends on the electric field in that depletion region, which means it depends on the voltage difference between the terminals.
If there is a high reverse voltage, it requires a lot of energy to push an electron through that region, which can be many times more than the band gap between the conduction band and valence band. Of course virtually no electrons would cross in the forward direction by themselves in that situation (but there are some that go in the reverse direction).
If there is a forward voltage (say about the knee-voltage of a diode) then the electric field in the depletion region becomes quite weak, and the energy needed to cross in the forward direction can be much less than the band gap. Lots of electrons will have enough thermal energy to make the crossing.
All of this should make clear that it simply isn't true that the work done by pushing an electron through the depletion region equals the energy gap between conduction band and valence band. It depends on the voltages.
